# Ext JS 6.2.0: Sorting of list items in a grid filter

Tags: extjs

I am referring to Sencha's documention of the [Ext.grid.filters.filter.List](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.List.html). If you run the code and open the filter for the 'Rating' column the filter values are not in natural ascending order but in their chronological order.[image]What needs to be done to change this and have the values in ascending order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually sort the filter values in ascending order before applying them to the column's filter. In the below code, the ratingValues array is generated by collecting unique 'rating' values from the store and sorting them in ascending order using the sort() method. The sorted array is then passed as the options property in the filter configuration for the 'Rating' column. This ensures that the filter values will be displayed in ascending order when the grid is rendered.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'show', 'rating'],
            data: [{
                id: 0,
                show: 'Battlestar Galactica',
                rating: 2
            }, {
                id: 1,
                show: 'Doctor Who',
                rating: 4
            }, {
                id: 2,
                show: 'Farscape',
                rating: 3
            }, {
                id: 3,
                show: 'Firefly',
                rating: 4
            }, {
                id: 4,
                show: 'Star Trek',
                rating: 1
            }, {
                id: 5,
                show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special',
                rating: 5
            }]
        });
        
        var ratingValues = shows.collect('rating', false, true).sort();
        
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
            height: 250,
            width: 350,
            store: shows,
            plugins: 'gridfilters',
            columns: [{
                dataIndex: 'id',
                text: 'ID',
                width: 50
            }, {
                dataIndex: 'show',
                text: 'Show',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                dataIndex: 'rating',
                text: 'Rating',
                width: 75,
                filter: {
                    type: 'list',
                    options: ratingValues,
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

[image]